# Microsoft Fakes Internal Classes Shim not generated

Tags: visual-studio-2012, microsoft-fakes, internalsvisibleto

I have Windows Form App(assembly named "**WindowsFormsApplication1**") and I have Unit Test project(assembly named "**UnitTestProject2**").

I added InternalsVisibleTo attribute into **"WindowsFormsApplication1\AssemblyInfo.cs"** like

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("UnitTestProject2")]
```

To access internal class from "WindowsFormsApplication1" into unit test app "UnitTestProject2" using Microsoft Fakes(VS 2012 Ultimate).

I can access internal class  directly using namespace from unit test project. *But I can not access Fakes - Shims and Stubs for that internal class.* 
I tried different combinations for InternalsVisibleTo attribute:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("UnitTestProject2.Fakes")], 
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("UnitTestProject2.Tests")]
```

etc. but none worked.

> Anyone have idea what went wrong and how to resolve it?

FYI: Reference - [Ref1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/115ce9e6-ac9d-4d9b-b3e5-0d38a7501495), [Ref2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708916.aspx#bkmk_internal_types).

Answer (score 5):

Suppose the assembly you are testing is 'WindowsFormsApplication1', then you have to add 2 InternalsVisibleTo attributes:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("WindowsFormsApplication1.Fakes")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("UnitTestProject2")]
```

MSDN:

> The Fakes code generator will generate shim types and stub types for types that are visible to the generated Fakes assembly. To make internal types of a shimmed assembly visible to Fakes and your test assembly, add InternalsVisibleToAttribute attributes to the shimmed assembly code that gives visibility to the generated Fakes assembly and to the test assembly.